# question mark ? in spring intercept-url (for resource versioning, query strings, ...)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

spring security file:

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources**" access="permitAll" /> 
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />


    <access-denied-handler error-page="/login"/>
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/planning/view" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        login-processing-url="/login?process" 
    /> 
    <logout logout-success-url="/login" /> 

</http>
```

I want to deny access to all pages except:
- login and login processing pages
- resources folder and subfolders

I should have the correct rules after searching a bit but they don't seem to work. I am not able to see the login?error page and it's not willing to login my user.

Comment: Try with `pattern="/login*"` and `pattern="/resources*"`

Comment: it works, (i changed login?process back to default). Do you perhaps have a reason why it's only working with a single star ?

Comment: ah i see, the security has problems with ? in the url, is there a way to allow question marks ?

Comment: `*` matches zero or more characters within the path name, while `**` matches zero or more characters in a tree of directories. The `**` is usually used like `/**/*.html` or `/login/**`.

Comment: Okay, it still stops at the ? (example: `/responsive.css?1.0` or `/login?error`)